# jQuery code never executed

Tags: jquery

I have jQuery code which is never executed. When I'm trying the same code in the browser console it works, so I don't understand why my code is never executed.

HTML CODE :

```
<div id="ans">
     <label>{$valeur}</label>
     <div class="radio">
         {foreach $reponse as $ligne}
             <input type="radio" name="answers" id="answer_{$ligne@iteration}" value="{$ligne@iteration}"/><label for="answer_{$ligne@iteration}">$ligne</label><br />
         {/foreach}
     </div>
</div>
```

Update :

```
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
  setTimeout(function(){
    $.post(ajax_path+"bla.php", {} , function(response) {
          $('#quest').html(response);
          $('#quest').collapse("show");
    })
    .fail(function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        {/literal}
        toastr.error(__['Error'], __['Error']);
        {literal}
    });
  }, 50);

  $('input[name=answers]').on('change', function () {
      $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });
});
```

Comment: Your jQuery probably loaded after `DOMContentLoaded`. Use `$( document ).ready`

Comment: Why do you mix vanilla JS with jQuery that way?

Comment: Already try it, It doesn't works.

Comment: @Mulan Then i guess you haven't included jquery correctly in your page

Comment: If my asnwer still does not fix your issue, please edit your question and add the HTML page.

Comment: In just about all modern browsers, `DOMContentLoaded` is exactly what jQuery's `document.ready` is using under the hood

Comment: @Mulan Have you loaded jQuery in you page?

Comment: Yes, there is another part of jquery code which is working.

Comment: What happens if you simply add an `alert("x")` inside the `addEventListener` ?

Comment: The alert appears

Comment: @adeneo it's not that simple.  On this SO page (now, once it's loaded), open the console and enter `document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() { alert("X"); });$(document).ready(function() { alert("Y"); })` - what happens?   You only get the Y alert, not the X.   Always use `$(document).ready()` regardless of what it might do in the background in some cases.

Comment: What about `alert($('input[name=answers]').length)` ?

Comment: 0 appears the alert

Comment: Does that explain your issue?  When your jquery runs, the DOM elements do not exist.  So you don't get the event handler assigned to them.  So your code is being executed, but there's nothing to execute it against.  It's most likely because your code runs before the HTML is generated - this may be because the HTML is added dynamically after the 'DOMContentLoaded' event - first change would be to use `$(function() ` (aka document.ready) but you say you've done that.  So next best guess is that you're using AJAX to load your radio buttons some time later.

Comment: Either add your event handler at the time you load the HTML (once loaded) or use event delegation:  Change your event handler to `$(document).on('change', 'input[name=answers]', function() {  $(this).closest("form").submit(); })`

Comment: @freedomn-m - the reason that works in the console, is because `DOMContentLoaded` fires when the entire  DOM has loaded *(not images etc)*, but it doesn't randomly fire after that. jQuery fires the `ready` handler at any given time, as long as it's after `DOMContentLoaded`. As long as the handler for `DOMContentLoaded` is in the DOM, and added before the event actually fires, it works the same way.

Comment: @adeneo that's exactly my point. They're not equivalent. DOMContentLoaded won't fire if already loaded while jquery doc.ready *does*.  So you can add jquery.doc ready calls and not have to worry about whether or not the page has already loaded.  There's too many "as long as"s in your comment for my liking :)

Comment: Indeed i'm using AJAX to load the radio buttons, I'll update my post with the ajax.

Comment: @freedomn-m - unless you place `DOMContentLoaded` inside async code, that isn't really an issue. Also, see [the source](https://github.com/jquery/jquery/blob/master/src/core/ready.js) line 80

Comment: @Mulan - would have been a good idea to lead with that information, as that's why your event handler doesn't work, it needs to be delegated

Comment: @Mulan in which case it's a common problem, but at least you have some new methods to find the issue.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/203198/event-binding-on-dynamically-created-elements

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {

    $('input[name=answers]').change(function() {

        $(this).closest("form").submit();
    });

});
```

try with this

Also, make sure selector is correct

## Edit

when you want to execute when all of page contents are loaded you can use load instead of ready

something like this

```
$(document).load(function() {
     $('input[name=answers]').change(function() {

         $(this).closest("form").submit();
     });
 })
```

Also, you can use window instead of document also

Comment: It still doesn't work.

The selector is correct, because when i try this code in the browser console it works.

Comment: I had to write on('load, function () {... to make it work, but my code is still never executed :/